# Can an object of a class be a member variable of some other class?

Tags: java

In `System.out.println`,'out' is a member variable of System class and it's also an instance of PrintStream class.So can anyone please tell me whether out can be a member of System class which is an object of PrintStream class or not?And please highlight me about System.out.println.

Comment: Reference - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *just* a public static final variable. Any time you write:

```
System.out.println("Foo");
```

you're fetching the value of that variable (which is a `PrintStream` reference) and calling `println()` on it. If it helps, think of it as:

```
PrintStream tmp = System.out;
tmp.println("Foo");
```

`System.out` is *not* an instance of `PrintStream` itself - it's a variable. The *value* of the variable isn't a `PrintStream` object, either - it's a *reference* to an object which is either a `PrintStream` or a subclass instance.

Comment: @Nim This question does make sense, may be not to you but to me.

Answer (score 1):

'out' is a public static final member of System class e.g.

```
public class System {
  public static final PrintStream out;
  static {
    out = new PrintStream()
    ........... // more initialisation
  }
}
```

To make a simpler example, you might easily include a String as a 'constant' in a class. That's still an object of class String being a member variable of some other class e.g.

```
public class MyWidget {
  public static final String WIDGET_NAME = "MyWidget";
  ... // other stuff
}
```

You can then access this string in the same way as you can access System.out:

```
System.out.println("Widget name length is " + MyWidget.WIDGET_NAME.length());
```